# PHP - local file repo security

Tags: php, apache, file-storage

I'm creating a file repository with a web-interface. Users will be able to log in (simple PHP authorisation system) and browse their files stored on the server. Each directory has a name, which determines to which user it belongs.

I'm struggling with securing the whole thing - I can't simply throw all the files into the document root, because everyone will be able to access them. All answers related to this problem suggest, that all private and sensitive data should be placed outside of the document root.
That's what I did, but now I can't find a way to show these files to the user when he logs in.

How should I approach this problem? Storing them in a database as BLOBs is a bad idea, because each file has over 1.5G.
The fact that these are video files which will be played by using a javascript plugin is also important - they need to be directly accessed by the user's browser.

**UPDATE**

For anyone struggling with the same issue:
I did as [Sherif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1878262/sherif) suggested in his answer. You need to install [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) and add

```
XSendFile On
XSendFilePath "/var/www/"
```

to your apache configuration file in the `<Directory>` section. Of course modify the path to suit your needs. Then create a PHP file which will handle the requests. Here's an example PHP-like pseudo code:

```
$file = $_GET["file"];
if (user_logged_in() && user_allowed_to_download($file)){
    $absoluteFilePath = "/var/www/".$file;
    header("X-Sendfile: ".$absoluteFilePath);
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file);
}
```

Then you can use it with jwplayer, VLC etc. like so:

```
<div class="embed_vlc_wrapper">
    <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
        width="500"
        height="500"
        version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
        target="http://localhost/xsend.php?file=1.mp4"
        pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: You can store files anywhere, and keep file names in the database.

Comment: @AlexBlex I know, but users need to access them directly in order to view their contents. Filenames won't be enough. Of course I could write a script that will temporarily copy each file to the document root upon request, and then (after it's downloaded by the user) delete it. But that's a horrible idea.

Comment: If "access them directly" means "download" you can use [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Comment: @AlexBlex I wish, the problem is that these are video files... they will be played by some javascript plugin like jwplayer. That's why the user's browser needs a direct access to these files. I was planning to create a simple script which would encrypt them in base_64, then I would use AJAX to retrieve them as an array of base_64 strings. But as I said - each file has over 1.5G. That's why I can't use this approach.

Comment: Then you should probably update the question with details what the "direct access" is. The docs I referred has an example of download proxy, so there is no difference on the other side of http connection, whether file is served by nginx as a static asset, or an output of php script. I strongly recommend to confirm it does not work with your clients "like jwplayer".

Comment: Why do you need to base_64 it? Don't change the file, send binary as it was uploaded.

Comment: @AlexBlex I updated the question as you suggested. I will try to do as you advised - send the binary data directly, without encoding it.

Comment: You will need to setup rewrite rules in your server, so requests like `/files/video.mkv` are changed to `download.php?file=video.mkv`, so you can analyse cookies, confirm authorisation, etc in download.php before proxying the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to go through your PHP for authentication and access the file outside of the document root that's fine. Just do normal authentication and then you can use `X-Sendfile` header to have your web server serve up the file from any location on your file system. See the documentation for your web server on how to enable sendfile: e.g. [Apache httpd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html), [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/#)

So here's the basic idea...

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_authenticated'])) { // or however you verify the user
    header('X-Sendfile: ', $pathToFileForDownload); // your web server will do the rest
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether I can use X-Sendfile with jwplayer or other javascript video plugins. Check out the last sentence in my updated question. Sorry for not including this information before.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. As long as the request is being made over http to your webserver the result is the same. PHP handles validating whether the person has rights to access the requested file, and your web server handles serving the file.